# How to switch provider into GPS_provider if android phone doesn't have internet connection?

Tags: java, android, android-manifest

i make a location application on android. here's the code for acquiring lat and long value.

```
public void geoLocation()
    {
        locationManager =(LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        locationListener = new LocationListener() {

            public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
              // Called when a new location is found by the network location provider.
                updateWithNewLocation(location);
            }
            public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {}
            public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
                Toast.makeText(ListenSMSservice.this,"Network Enabled",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show(); 
            }
            public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
                Toast.makeText(ListenSMSservice.this,"Network Disabled",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();
            }
          };
        // Register the listener with the Location Manager to receive location updates
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListener);
    }

    public void updateWithNewLocation(Location location) //update posisi terkini
    {
        if (location != null) {
            lat = location.getLatitude();
            lng = location.getLongitude();

            Geocoder gc = new Geocoder(ListenSMSservice.this, Locale.getDefault());
            try {
              List<Address> addresses = gc.getFromLocation(lat, lng, 1);
              StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
              if (addresses.size() > 0) {
                Address address = addresses.get(0);

                for (int i = 0; i < address.getMaxAddressLineIndex(); i++)
                  sb.append(address.getAddressLine(i)).append("\n");

                  sb.append(address.getLocality()).append("\n");
                  sb.append(address.getCountryName());
              }
              addressString = sb.toString();
            } catch (IOException e) {}

            //latLongString = "Lat:" + lat + "\nLong:" + lng;     
            latLongUrl="Phone Map\nhttp://maps.google.com/maps?q=" + lat + ",+" + lng + "+(Your+phone+location)&iwloc=A&hl=en\n";
          } else {
            latLongUrl = "No location found"; 
          }
          myMessage=latLongUrl+"\n"+addressString;
          locationManager.removeUpdates(locationListener); 
          locationManager = null;
          //Toast.makeText(ListenSMSservice.this, myMessage, 3).show();
          sendsms();
    }
```

that code will works if i have an internet connection (`NETWORK_PROVIDER`). has anyone know how to modify that code for automatically switch into `GPS_PROVIDER` when android phone doesn't have any internet connection?? thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`onLocationUpdate()` just check for Internet is available or not,

If `Internet is not available` then just,

```
   locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListener);
```

so like this,

```
ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
NetworkInfo netInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
if (netInfo != null && netInfo.isConnected()) {
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListener);
} else {
    return false;
}
```

EDIT: Here you can find beautiful explanation about Hoe to get current location,

[What is the simplest and most robust way to get the user's current location in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3145089/what-is-the-simplest-and-most-robust-way-to-get-the-users-current-location-in-a/3145655#3145655)

please refer this also.

Thanks